# how can I add a countdown in c# right after my game ends?

Tags: c#, countdown

how do I add a countdown from 5 to 1 right after my game ends?

I tried using this `

```
int countdownStartValue = 5;
        void start()
        {

        }
        void countdownTimer()
        {
            if (countdownStartValue > 0)
            {
                countdownStartValue--;
                Invoke('countdownTimer', 1.0f);
                countdownTimer();

            }
        }
```

but it seems to be wrong

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589316/creating-a-countdown-clock/55591821#55591821

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `Thread.Sleep()` in this case.

```
 int countdownStartValue = 5;
    void start()
    {

    }
    void countdownTimer()
    {
        while (countdownStartValue > 0)
        {
             countdownStartValue--;
             Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

The current running thread (program) will sleep for 1 second before continuing to run

Comment: In most cases this is the worst way to achieve any kind of timer. It will lock the thread up which means it can't update any GUI elements so it won't even work on anything except maybe a background thread.

Comment: @LukeBriner great point, what would be the optimal way of doing so ?